# Navigation Stack Error - TF Exception that should never happen for sensor fram

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, transform, avoid-obstacle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I make a autonomous differential robot. In kinetic devel navigation stack works fine. Robot can get position, goes goal, escape obstacle....However i upgrade my linux and ros base to melodic devel.

In melodic devel i get the error. My robot doesn't avoid from obstacles.I cant solve this... Is there any solution?

Warning: Invalid argument "/laser" passed to canTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like:
at line 134 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-tf2-0.6.5/src/buffer_core.cpp
[ERROR] [1601902625.778502017]: TF Exception that should never happen for sensor frame: , cloud frame: /laser, Invalid argument "/laser" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like:

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362847/navigation-stack-error---tf-exception-that-should-never-happen-for-sensor-fram/) by [bfdmetu](https://answers.ros.org/users/45011/bfdmetu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2020-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem. In laser scanner package, frame name is "/laser"... I ommit the "/" then it works

---

Originally posted by [bfdmetu](https://answers.ros.org/users/45011/bfdmetu/) with karma: 85 on 2020-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vvb](https://answers.ros.org/users/87586/vvb/) on 2021-10-19**:
I have the same issue. Could you please elaborate a little bit more on this. I get issues while I'm trying to run the TEB local planner.